# How to Display quoteText from the response of this API Object

Tags: reactjs

Random Quote

How to display the quoteText and quoteAuthor separately from this object for my random quote machine app.I have tried the standard way by writing {this.state.quote.quoteText}.

Here is the response object that I have got from my API.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKtH7.jpg):[response object of API]

+Code Snippets

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QepXQ.jpg):[code snippet-1]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS00L.jpg):[code snippet-2]

Comment: can you please post more code?

Comment: Please add some code what you tried.

Comment: Add the code not the screenshot

Comment: And what is the error or issue you are facing?

Comment: I am not able to extract quoteText and quoteAuthor separately from that response object to display it.

Comment: Please paste your code from the VSCode to this question and let us help with that.

Comment: I have added the code snippet for your convenience....

Answer (score 0):

May be when the component is mounted your data is not yet fetched so here is one possible solution. On line number 37 where you have done this

```
{this.state.quote !== null  && <p>{this.state.quote}</p>}
```

Instead Try this

```
this.state.quote.quoteText ? this.state.quote.quoteText  : "";
```

Also on line number 23 where you have done  this

```
axions.get("the url") 
    .then((res) => { this.setState({
        quote: res.data
       }) 
        })
```

Add this line of code

```
 .then((response) => response.json())
```

so your code will look like this

```js
axions.get("the url")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((res) => {
    this.setState({
      quote: res.data
    })
  })
```

**Even if that fails try this code that uses fetch  **

```js
fetch("the url goes here", {
    method: 'GET'
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {

      this.setState({
        quote: data.response
      })
```

> you can call this fetch API directly in componentDidMount()  lifecycle .

Comment: Before setting the api response in the state on line number 23 you have to use this .then((response) => response.json()) let me edit my answer so that you may understand it well